# SignalR error with Mono on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, signalr

I am trying to execute some C# code on a Raspberry Pi, specifically some SignalR code.

But the thing is that it compiles just fine, creates the executable, but when I run it I get this error.

[HubConnection could not be loaded from SignalR Assembly in Raspberry Pi Mono Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060026/hubconnection-could-not-be-loaded-from-signalr-assembly-in-raspberry-pi-mono-pro)

Basically, I have the same problem, except that the answer from there (sudo apt-get install mono-complete) doesn't work for me, because I already have it up to date.

I get this error :

```
Could not load type 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.HubConnection' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client'
```

This is the source code which works fine on Windows and Xamarin(MacOS):

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://mspmaplocator.azurewebsites.net");
            var hub = hubConnection.CreateHubProxy("MapHub");

            hub.On<string, string>("onMarkerPlace", (latitude,longitude) => Console.WriteLine("Latitude: {0} \nLongitude: {1}\n", latitude, longitude));

            hubConnection.Start().Wait();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

When I compile this code with macs, I do it like this in the terminal.

```
mcs Program.cs -r:Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client.dll
```

Even if it works in Xamarin Studio, it still doesn't work in the Mac OS terminal or Linux terminal(tried Ubuntu and Raspberry).

Do I need to compile it differently or against other libraries?

Thanks!

Comment: @Sreeraj I know you had this problem with RPi and SignalR a while back. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the SignalR library and System, System.Web are compatible with one another. This may happen if either you don't run using these libraries, or if they are different versions.